# How to access local variables while handling ctrl-C event?

Tags: python, interrupt, sigint

I wondered if it is possible to access variables local to the function running at the time ctrl-C interrupts the flow.  Example, where main() is running when ctrl-C is pressed:

```
def main(myInfo):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, KeyboardBreak)
    reportOut(myInfo)

def KeyboardBreak(signum, frame):
    reportOut(myInfo)

def reportOut(myInfo):
    print myInfo
```

I would like reportOut() to run whether main() gets all the way down to where it calls reportOut(), or the flow is interrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal handler needs access to the variable `myInfo`. The easiest way to do this is to define `KeyboardBreak()` *inside* `main()` so that it has access to `myInfo` via closure.

```
def main(myInfo):

    def KeyboardBreak(signum, frame):
        reportOut(myInfo)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, KeyboardBreak)
    reportOut(myInfo)

def reportOut(myInfo):
    print myInfo
```

Alternatively, you can write a factory function that *creates* your signal handler, again using a closure to hold `myInfo`. This approach is probably best when either of these functions is complex.

```
def main(myInfo):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, KeyboardBreakFactory(myinfo))
    reportOut(myInfo)

def KeyboardBreakFactory(myinfo):

    def KeyboardBreak(signum, frame):
        reportOut(myInfo)

    return KeyboardBreak

def reportOut(myInfo):
    print myInfo
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you, it works.  Helpful to see both the easiest way and the better way.